# How to map several database fields to one TextView located at ListView?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

Here is the code with 1-to-1 field mapping:

```
String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, 
        DbAdapter.KEY_OPEN_TIME,
        DbAdapter.KEY_FAVORITE};

int[] to = new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.time, R.id.icon};

SimpleCursorAdapter lists = 
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, listsCursor, from, to);
```

But I have another field in my database - `DbAdapter.KEY_CLOSE_TIME` and `R.id.time` should display value like `DbAdapter.KEY_OPEN_TIME + " - " + DbAdapter.KEY_CLOSE_TIME`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend `CursorAdapter`, you'll have more controll over view.

[Tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/)

Comment: I've found that the same is possible with `setViewValue`